# create a dynamic php url

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I am trying to create a dynamic url that looks like this localhost/wordpress/slug/username

I am using the wp_redirect function to redirect the user to this url but the probleme is that i don't know how to write this url ?

I've tried to create a variable like so `$user = wp_get_current_user();` to includ it like so `wp_redirect( "http://localhost/wordpress/slug/$user->display_name" );` but the final result is `http://localhost/wordpress2/slug/` so please someone help me

keep in mind that i'm writing my code in the function.php file in my theme folder

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the function inside a hook? I use the `template_redirect` action for actual redirects. The `wp_get_current_user` function may not be defined if you're calling it too soon.

Comment: sorry but i'm not a wp expert ,, so what is a hook? and how do i use 'template_redirect' .... well i think that the variable doesn't return any value and thats the probleme ... maybe as you said the function isn't defined but as i said i'm adding my code into function.php and this file is located under   C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\my_theme

Comment: WordPress provides loads of these hooks to tap into the WP core code execution. There are actions and filters. `template_redirect` is one of the available actions to hook onto.

Comment: thank you for the answer ,,, but while im reading more about this hooks now, can you plz tell me how to modify my code ( i know i'm stupid but i'm just begener wp user not even a wp developper ) ,,, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
wp_redirect( "http://localhost/wordpress/slug/$user->display_name" );
```

to

```
wp_redirect( "http://localhost/wordpress/slug/".$user->display_name);
```

Try to use `bloginfo('url')` instead of using `localhost/wordpress`

Comment: With regards to the first part of your answer, I had the same thought so I just looked it up: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing  `$user->display_name` shouldn't be the problem (unless the variable itself is empty?)

Comment: tahts what i also think ,,, the variable is empty ,,, maybe i'm not writnig the complete code or i should show the location of the function i'm using ,,,,, oooohhhh thats too complicated for me ,,,, plz help

Comment: @raveenanigam `$user = wp_get_current_user();


add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'create_tab3', 303 );
function create_tab3() {
    global $bp;
    bp_core_new_nav_item(
        array(
            'name'                    => 'myname',
            'slug'                    => 'slug', 
            'position'                => 21, 
  'default_subnav_slug'     => 'myname', 
  'screen_function'         => 'redirect_user_to_tab3',
        )
    );
 
}
function redirect_user_to_tab3(){
    global $bp;
    wp_redirect( "http://localhost/wordpress/slug/$user->display_name" );
 exit;
}`

Comment: @raveenanigam comon buddy plzz help ,,,,,,, i've read about hooks and tried so many codes but none of theme worked ,,, the  thing is i'm not a programmer ,,,, i started learn php with codecademy.com but ineed the solution now ,,,, plzzzzz

Comment: @raveenanigam,,,,, you see from my code that i try to add a tab in buddypress tabs ,,, but i don't know if my code is correct so that when someone visits other user profile and click this tab i want it to show the page of the user visited and not the visitor ;;;; i hope alot from you so plzzzz help ,,,, i already started to learn some php from codecademy